# Is the Ethereum 2.0 price fixed to the old Ethereum permanently?

Tags: exchanges, eth-2.0

I read that it will be possible to convert one old Ether for one Ether 2.0 **but not vice versa**.

Is this correct and does the **algorithm guarantee** this "exchange rate" **forever** (and thus protect the old Ether from becoming worthless if everybody switches)?

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that no one answered my question because the answer seems really easy. I still don't know very much about cypto currencies but my question was based on a misconception.

It will never be possible to *exchange ETH 1.0 for ETH 2.0*. **There will not be a new type of ETH token.**
Old Ether will just be changed into new Ether. Basically the old technology will be abandoned (proof of work, aso) and all the old funds live on in the new blockchain.

The other thing I was confused about was *validating the beacon chain by staking ETH*. If you stake now you don't really buy ETH 2.0. It just blocks your Ether until it is possible to perform normal transactions on Ethereum 2.0. This feature will be rolled out in update 1.5 (currently there is no information on when or even if this will happen).

- Staking is a "one-way transaction" at the moment.
- Old and new Ether will have "the same value" forever (because it will be merged)

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Check out this site for more:
https://consensys.net/knowledge-base/ethereum-2/faq